# Render on TextInput Submit - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios

In a a react native app I have some text and then a textinput rendered on the screen. I'm trying to figure out how to output the same text and the same textinput when I submit on in the original text field. I was thinking to do this recursively but I'm not sure how where and how implement the function to do so.

Comment: are you trying to output the same text & same textinput on new screen or same screen ?

Comment: @SastraNababan on the same screen, below the original

Answer (score 0):

If it's in the same screen, than you can use local state. here's the example

```
class TestScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this. state = { 
      firstInput:'First Input',
      secondInput:''
    }
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)
  }

  submit(){
    this.setState({ secondInput: this.state.firstInput })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,marginTop:40}}>

        <View>
          <Text>Text Input #1</Text>
          <TextInput  
             style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}} 
             onChangeText={(text)=> this.setState({firstText:text})}
             value={this.state.firstInput}
            />
            <Button 
              onPress={this.submit}
              title="Submit"
            />
        </View>

        <View style={{marginTop:20}}>
          <Text>Text Input #1</Text>
          <TextInput 
          style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
          value={this.state.secondInput}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I hope that help. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. What you mean indefinitely ?

Comment: Sorry I only glanced at the example. This is not what I am trying to do. After submitting in a textinput I want to add and new empty text input to the screen after submitting

Comment: Not simply replace the valve in the text field

Answer (score 0):

Perhap you can use ref,state,conditional rendering. let's code talk

```
const MyInputs = (props) => {
  inputs =props.inputs
  result=inputs.map(function(value,index){
    return(
      <TextInput key={index} style={styles.input} value={value} />
    )  
  })

  return(
    <View>
      {result}
    </View>
  )
}


class TestScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this. state = { 
      inputs:[]  
    }
    this.submit = this.submit.bind(this)
    this.clearText = this.clearText.bind(this)
  }

  submit(){
    let lastInput=this._textInput._lastNativeText
    let inputs=this.state.inputs
    this._textInput.setNativeProps({text: ''});
    inputs.push(lastInput)
     this.setState({ 
      inputs:inputs
    })
  }

  clearText = () => {
    this.setState({ 
      inputCount: this.state.inputCount + 1,
    })
    this._textInput.setNativeProps({text: ''});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1,marginTop:40}}>
        <View>
          <Text>Text Input #1</Text>
          <TextInput  
             style={styles.input} 
             ref={component => this._textInput = component}
          />
          <Button onPress={this.submit} title="Submit"
          />
        </View>

        <MyInputs inputs={this.state.inputs}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something but what is <MyInputs> in this

Comment: I just add missing MyInput Component